# Url Rewrite 2.0 Rewrite wont take affect

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

So basically i have made this blank rule:
[image]

But when i navigate to http://myurl.com/default i get a 404, But am expecting it to go to page http://myurl.com/Default.aspx I have no idea why it is not? I have tested other rules such as adding a `/` to the end of a URL or removing a `/` from the end of a URL and these both work, but for some reason another blank rule I create just will no work? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your `web.config` does contain the rule?

Comment: Its cool i figured out what was going on this was an old question of mine, there was some logic in the global.asax interfering with this